# Can resharper javascript intellisense refer to js files in another project in a solution?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, resharper, intellisense

We have a set of javascript files which reside in one project in our solution, but are referred to in several other projects.

Resharper 6.1's intellisense is picking up the files within the project they reside, but not in the other web projects where they are used.

Is there any way to make resharper javascript intellisense apply across the whole solution?

Comment: +1 Good question - the only thing I can suggest and it really doesn't answer your question....is putting `/// <reference path="~/path.js" />` to get the intellisense support, but this is not global and requires (potentially) a lot of lines of reference 'includes' to put in your files and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

A solution can be like this:
Add a JsRef folder to the project you want to use external refs.
Add the desired files as link to the folder.
After a while, you will get the intellisense for the classes and functions.

Answer (score 1):

No... As of the latest version of ReSharper, there is no support for Javascript intellisense from external projects.  It might be worth suggesting this to the ReSharper team to consider in future releases.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-273040

Comment: This bug is marked as fixed but it still seems to be broken in Resharper 7... Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

As long as a have a reference to web application or class library where js file is resided intellisense is working for me.

Comment: Because of IOC, we don't want to do this, but I guess this will work for some cases.

Comment: I'm not sure that having intellisense include all js files in solution is a very good idea, seems to me that it can lead to run time errors if js files wasn't included on the page. But I guess it's possible to write an R# addin that'll do what you want.

Comment: The files we need are referenced in the page, otherwise as you say would fail at runtime. The problem is that R# seems to ignore JS file references, and uses .net dll references to find what to index for intellisense.